# ubuntu 13.10 kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64

Tags: 13.10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I just upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 and I have this issue when I run my KVM

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
char device redirected to /dev/pts/10 (label charserial0)
failed to initialize KVM: Device or resource busy
```

Detail Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 96, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1983, in do_install
    guest.start_install(False, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1246, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtinst/Guest.py", line 1314, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 2892, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
char device redirected to /dev/pts/8 (label charserial0)
failed to initialize KVM: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with sudo? On my machine it is a privilege problem.

Comment: Still the same error    Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: W: kvm binary is deprecated, please use qemu-system-x86_64 instead
char device redirected to /dev/pts/9 (label charserial0)
failed to initialize KVM: Device or resource busy

Comment: I have that same error sometimes. It happens also if I have a virtualbox instance running, those two are incompatible. 



Thee error message is coming from `/usr/bin/kvm` (take a look into it with cat), so it seems kvm used a binary before, but now it doesn't. Did you load the kernel module? If I do a `lsmod | grep kvm`, I see kvm and kvm_intel. If they are not there you should build them.

Comment: Hi Edgar You are right about this. I can see kvm and kvm_intel. And how should I solve this?

Comment: If you see them, it should be ok. Maybe your image is not in the correct directory? On my system it is a bit sensitive. Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307950/virt-install-error. If that doesn't work, it would be helpful if you put the whole log in a pastebin.

Comment: And can you try disable apparmor temporaly. `service apparmor teardown`, it caused problems with my virtual machines.

Comment: Hi Edgar, it doesn't work for me. How to enable apparmor again?

Comment: `sudo service apparmor start` would do the trick. I am sorry, but I am out of options, there is something strange into your setup I didn't have. I gave a bad advice there, I should have said, that you run an application in complain mode `aa-complain virt-manager`. You didn't have to stop apparmor completely.

Comment: Hi Edgar, never mind. You just want to help me and make it work.

Answer (score 3):

It's apparently a problem with virsh. Just try and start the virtual machine using directly the command that's advised in the error message, like this

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda [wherever your created virtual disk is]
```

It's apparently [a bug in virt-manager](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1223323) that has not been fixed yet. [This user found the solution](https://superuser.com/questions/606923/error-while-creating-a-vm-using-kvm) by changing the XML definition of the VM.

Comment: Any solution to fix this issue instead of using command to start?

Answer (score 1):

For reference to other people in need that maybe don't edit domain definition every day.

The problem is just as in the error message: the executable of the emulator has changed, so the definition file of the VM must be updated.

- from a command shell and as root or a user that can use the libvirt system, start `virsh`
- `list --all`
- check the correct domain name of your VM, let's say it's `vm_name`
- `edit vm_name`
- search for the tag `<emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>`
- replace it with `<emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>`
- save the file
- `start vm_name`

Please note that depending on the age of the VM definition and the system under which it was created, the old emulator executable could be different than simplu kvm, but replace it anyway :-)

In addition: other that this I had another problem: some VM disk image files had the wrong permissions, like root:root or root:kvm. It seems that as of 13.10 in January 2014, they should be libvirt-qemu:kvm

Answer (score 0):

I was using Virtual Machine Manager and encountered this error. Solved when I used 'qemu' as hypervisor type when creating the VM.